# Ubuntu: is there a better file manager than Nautilus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

Is there a package readily available that can replace & enhance the functionality of Nautilus?

Comment: what enhancements are you looking for? If we know what you want to do, maybe there are other applications better suited than extending nautilus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look at the KDE world, there is dolphin. And if you prefer two-panel file-manager, you can try krusader. Both are installable via a apt-get install.

Comment: +1 for dolphin and krusader.  There are also dual-pane file managers that use GTK, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Actually, with Nautilus you can enable an additional panel, too :)

Comment: Pressing F3 in nautilus brings you an additional panel.

Answer (score 10):

[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/)! Just type mc from any command prompt.

Comment: are you serious? this feels so 1980's.

Comment: The 80's rocked!  And it all depends on your definition of "better" doesn't it? :-)

Comment: Some people with a history of DOS and similar still prefer the two-pane text-based file management interface. Strange but true. I'm bash command-line person myself, preferring it over most graphical interfaces. To each his own!

Comment: i have no clue why MC is so popular and so often brought up as a file manager replacement.

Comment: mc helps me fondly recall the DOS days and the wonders of Norton Commander :-)

Comment: @Roy, MC is a clone of Norton Commander. And Norton Commander was pretty much the grand daddy of file managers.

Comment: @A Dwarf: And the granddaddy of total commander not to forget, which is very popular in the windows world today.

Answer (score 10):

Thunar is a decent light weight replacement.

http://thunar.xfce.org/index.html

Comment: +1 Thunar has some really nice features not found in Nautilus: custom actions, mouse gestures (very nice), to name just two

Answer (score 2):

While it has a few peculiarities, I've had mostly positive experiences with [ROX](http://roscidus.com/desktop/)  when I've had a need for a graphical file manager.  It's much lighter than nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

I love mc, and wouldn't use anything else.  But, if it's too 80's for you, you can get [gnome-commander](http://www.nongnu.org/gcmd/) from the repos.

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin has Miller Column view like Mac OSX 's finder. I like that feature very much!

Comment: Miller columns in Dolphin are [gone](https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg143082.html), Pantheon File Manager (Elementary Distribution) has it but it is very buggy, at least in my Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Surprised not to see the `pcmanfm` File Manager here!
If speed is something you **really** want, PCManFM is a superb option! :)

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```